# how to pass Drop Down List value as a parameter for stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

I'm creating two DROP DOWN LIST that are basically bind, one for **PROVINCE** and one for **CITY**. 
I have a C# web app project:
I want the list of **cities** to change according to the selected item in the **PROVINCE** drop down list.
But ***every time I select a new item from the PROVINCE list, the data in the CITY list does not change.***
I don't know where the problem is. Is it in the SELECTED INDEX CHANGED or ...?
tnx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication3_DrpDwnListAndSQL
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                func1();
                func2();
                //func3();
            }
        }

        protected void DrpDwnProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = DrpDwnProvince.SelectedValue;
            //string a = DrpDwnProvince.SelectedValue;
        }




        //First function for Province DrpDwnList 
        private void func1()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DrpBoxDB;Data Source=ARASH-PC");
            SqlDataAdapter com = new SqlDataAdapter("_Province_selectAll", con);
            com.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            if (com != null)
            { com.Fill(ds); }

            DrpDwnProvince.DataSource = ds;
            DrpDwnProvince.DataTextField = "Prv_Name";
            DrpDwnProvince.DataValueField = "Prv_Id";
            DrpDwnProvince.DataBind();
        }

        //Second function for City DrpDwnList
        private void func2()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DrpBoxDB;Data Source=ARASH-PC");
            SqlDataAdapter com1 = new SqlDataAdapter("_City_selectItems", con);
            com1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vari", DrpDwnProvince.SelectedValue);
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            if (com1 != null)
            { com1.Fill(ds1); }

            DrpDwnCity.DataSource = ds1;
            DrpDwnCity.DataTextField = "Cty_Name";
            DrpDwnCity.DataValueField = "Cty_Id";
            DrpDwnCity.DataBind();
        }

        //Third function for District DrpDwnList
       // private void func3()
       // {

      //  }


    }
}
```

Comment: yes just bind your dropdownlist on selected index change event and try dropdownlist.selectedindex instead of selectedvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that the `AutoPostBack="true"` attribute is not set on your DropDownList in the .aspx file. That is required in order to have the page respond when the user selects a different item.

E.g.:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DrpDwnProvince" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpDwnProvince_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
```

**Update:** Per comments below - looks like the problem was that func2() was not getting called in the event handler. So solution would be something like:

```
protected void DrpDwnProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    func2();
}
```

Comment: hi QuadrupleA, I've checked it and the autopostback is true on the dropdownlist but ...

Comment: Hi Arash - so Label1 never displays the dropdown value when Province is changed?

Comment: It looks like you might just need to call `func2();` in the `DrpDwnProvince_SelectedIndexChanged()` method, to display the cities.

Comment: label 1 shows the changes of the province, but the changes of the province does not effect the city drpdwnlist. the data in the city drpdwnlist is always the same.

Comment: OK - I think you just need to call `func2()` in your dropdown event handler. It won't work in `Page_Load()` the way you have it, as that won't get called on postbacks.

Comment: Cool - I'll add that to the answer.